# React Router: this.props.params not updated after Link click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm building a simple react app with a sidebar. from it, I want to swap out the various categories of the app.

My router looks like this:

```
<Route path={path} component={App}>
   <IndexRoute component={HomeView} />
   <Route path="/" component={HomeView} />
   <Route path="/manage" component={LoggedInView} />
   <Route path="/search/:topic" component={SearchView} />
   <Route path="/c/:category" component={CategoryView} />
   <Route path="*" component={ErrorView} type="404"/>
</Route>
```

In the sidebar I have a link like this:

```
  <Link to={{ pathname: '/c/'+el.urlkey}} activeClassName="active"{el.title}</Link>
```

Finally in the CategoryView I have this variable:

```
   let queryParam = this.props.params.category;
```

When I click the Link, the url in the urlbar changes, but the category doesn't. When I click it again, the category changes as well.

If I log the 'queryParam ', I see that the first time I click, it returns the same value. only after the second click does it change.

Why isn't it changing on the first click? I've also tried routing programmatically using

```
 this.props.router.push(url);
```

But the issue still occurs.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

- EDIT

This is the code for the Categoryview

```js
@pureRender
class Category extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      activeCategoryName: '',
      activeCategory: {},
      availableTopics: {},
      ...
    };
  }


  componentWillReceiveProps() {
    this.showCategory();
  }

  componentWillMount(){
    this.showCategory();
  }

  showCategory(){
    const self = this;
    let queryParam = this.props.params.category;
    const availableCategories = this.props.categories;
    let matched = false;

    const count = availableCategories.length - 1;
    if(count === -1){
      this.setState({
        notFound: true
      });
    } else {
      filter(availableCategories, function (el, index) {
        const categoryTitle = el.urlkey.toLowerCase();
        const activeLocale = self.props.activeLocale;
        let title = null;
        if (queryParam !== undefined) {
          title = queryParam.toLowerCase();
        }
```

Comment: Post the code for your CategoryView component. Issue is likely how you're hooking into props

Comment: I just added it, Thanks for looking into it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're seeing the old data when you click the second time, is because componentWillReceiveProps executes before `this.props` is updated with that information. Update the method to do this instead:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.showCategory(nextProps);
}

showCategory(props) {
  let queryParam = props.params.category;
  // etc
}
```

In terms of the first one not showing up, try passing `this.props` (with the changes above) in a componentDidMount instead of componentWillMount. I realize this causes a new render to run, but I wonder if the props aren't initialized yet. If that doesn't fix it, I think you need to debug the details in your filter function, and see if setState is being called.

Comment: Thanks so much. So obvious but have been staring at it for hours

Answer (score 1):

Pass your props to `showCategory function` so that it can update the new value whenever a new props arrive into the component

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
 this.showCategory(nextProps);
}

componentWillMount(this.props){
 this.showCategory(this.props);
}

showCategory(props){
 const self = this;
 let queryParam = props.params.category;
 const availableCategories = props.categories;
 let matched = false;

 const count = availableCategories.length - 1;
 if(count === -1){
  this.setState({
    notFound: true
  });
 } else {
    filter(availableCategories, function (el, index) {
    const categoryTitle = el.urlkey.toLowerCase();
    const activeLocale = self.props.activeLocale;
    let title = null;
    if (queryParam !== undefined) {
      title = queryParam.toLowerCase();
    }

    if(categoryTitle === title && el.language === activeLocale){
      matched = true;
      self.setState({
        activeCategoryName: categoryTitle,
        activeCategory: el,
        notFound: false,
        isLoading: false,
        isEmpty: false
      });
    } else if(index === count && !matched){
      self.setState({
        isEmpty: true,
        isLoading: false
      });
    }
  });
}
}
```